# Trying to create fixed transparent menu but want h1 to be centered for responsive design and .intro to be moved down without making a gap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a fixed nav. For the most part, it works. But I want to center the h1 for responsive design. I could just push it away from the burger menu but then it wouldn't be responsive and bang in the middle.

Also I would like to push the .intro paragraph down away from the top. But every time I do a margin gap appears at the top, and I can't for the life of me remember how to get rid of this.

Thank you to anyone who takes a look. Means a lot! Hopefully one day I can repay the favor!

Below is my HTML and CSS. I also used a standard normalize.css, and some Js but I don't think you will need that. If you do, let me know:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Code Review</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>



  <!-- Introduction -->

  <div class="background">

    <nav class="navbar">
      <span class="open-slide" onclick="openSideMenu()">


<!--          <a href="#" onclick="openSideMenu()">-->

          <svg width="30" height="30">
            <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4"/>
            <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4"/>
            <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4"/>
          </svg>


<!--          </a>-->
      </span>

      <div id="main">
        <h1><a href="#">Luke Bennett</a></h1>
      </div>

<!--
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
-->

    </nav>

  <!-- Side Navigation Bar -->

    <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
      <span class="btn-close exit" onclick="closeSideMenu()">&times;</span>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a onclick="closeSideMenu()" href="#about">About</a>
      <a onclick="closeSideMenu()" href="#portfolio-link">Portfolio</a>
      <a onclick="closeSideMenu()" href="#resume-link">Resume</a>
      <a onclick="closeSideMenu()" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <p class="intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>

</header>

<main>

  <!-- About Me -->

  <div class="about-me"><a id="about"></a>

    <h2>About Me</h2>

    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 

    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>

  </div>

  <!-- Portfolio -->

  <div class="portfolio"><a id="portfolio-link"></a>

    <h2>Portfolio</h2>

    <!-- Front Page -->
    <a href="http://www.donjaswell-beingforkids.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img src="img/well-being/well-being.png" alt="Donjas-Well-Being-For-Kids"/></a>

  </div>

  <!-- Resume -->

  <div class="resume">
    <a href="documents/Luke-Bennett-Resume.pdf" id="resume-link" target="_blank">Download Resume</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Contact Form -->

  <div class="contact-form"><a id="contact"></a>

    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Form</legend>

        <ul>

          <li>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input required type="text" id="name" name="full_name" placeholder="Required">
          </li>

          <li>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input required type="text" id="email" name="email_address" placeholder="Required">
          </li>

          <li>
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="other_topics"></textarea>
          </li>

          <button type="submit">Hello!</button>

        </ul>

      </fieldset>          
    </form>

  </div>

</main>

<footer>

  <p>My name is Luke Bennett and I am a Human - Luke Bennett</p>

</footer>

<script src="javascript/menu.js"></script>
```

```
    *,
input,
textarea,
button {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/************************************************************
HEADER
*************************************************************/

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  align-items: center;

}

#main {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main a {
  color: black;
}

.background {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, transparent 40%),
              #333333 url('../img/sophie.jpg')  no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.intro {
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.65;
  line-height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 15% 15%;
}

/************************************************************
SIDE NAV
*************************************************************/

svg {
  padding-top: 3px;
  transition: 1s;
/*
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
*/
}

svg:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.side-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333333;
  opacity: 0.9;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 90px;
}

.side-nav a,
.btn-close {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.side-nav a:hover,
.btn-close:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 22px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}



/************************************************************
MAIN
*************************************************************/

main {
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.about-me {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.about-me h2 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.about-me h2,
.about-me p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.about-me p {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}



/************************************************************
PORTFOLIO
*************************************************************/

.portfolio {
  background: #DCEAF5;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 50px;
}

.portfolio h2 {
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.portfolio img {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 3px;
  transition: 1s;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.portfolio img:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

/************************************************************
RESUME
*************************************************************/

/* #DCEAF5 #659EB8 */

.resume {
  display: flex;
  background: #969DA3;
  padding: 10%;
}

.resume a {
  display: block;
  background: #DCEAF5;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 7%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.resume a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}


/************************************************************
CONTACT
*************************************************************/

.contact-form {
  background: #cc8c33;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 20% 10%;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

label {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input,
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border: 2px solid #969DA3;
  outline: none;
}

input {
  border-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #cc8c33;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

::placeholder {
  text-align: right;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  padding-right: 1px;
}

/* Textarea styling */

textarea {
  height: 110px;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #cc8c33;
}

/* Button styling */

button {
  border: none;
  background: lightblue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover {
  background: #DCEAF5;
  color: black;
}

/************************************************************
SOCIAL
*************************************************************/

footer {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Can u create a repro?

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for taking a look at my post, yes I do have one, I should have included it sorry: https://github.com/LukeBennettUK/portfolio